# HTML5 validation on lists

Tags: html, kendo-ui

How can I do HTML5 required validation on a group of check boxes? I basically have an option such as "choose one or more of the following", with several checkboxes inside an ul. 
If I set required attribute at the ul level, nothing happens. If I set it at the input level, it makes it so every value must be checked to validate. I want it to force the user to pick at least one value. This seems to work fine with Radio type, but with checkboxes (where you can have more then one choice) it does not work.

Here's the HTML:

```
  <form> 
   <!-- in this case, I set required at the ul level !-->
   <ul required="required" validationMessage="You must enter a gender">
      <li>
        <input id="male" name="mf" type="checkbox" value="Male" />
        <label  for="male">Male</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <input id="female" name="mf"  type="checkbox" value="Female" />
        <label for="female">Female</label>
      </li>
    </ul>
   <!-- in this case, I set it at the input level -->
   <ul required="required" validationMessage="You must enter a gender2">
      <li>
        <input id="male2" name="mf2" type="checkbox" value="Male2" required />
        <label  for="male">Male2</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <input id="female2" name="mf2" type="checkbox" value="Female2" required />
        <label for="female">Female2</label>
      </li>
    </ul>
   <input type="submit" value="submit">
  </form>
```

I should note: I am using Kendo to make the validation work across browsers (in case there's a Kendo-ized solution to this problem)

Comment: Surely a gender decision should be a radio box

Comment: @Andy Think more liberal man. C'mon it's 2013...

Comment: I only created this as a sample for this post... please use your imagination ;)